# Does this sentence make sense? “There's no such thing as an oversized commitment that is too big for one to dedicate oneself to.”

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I was writing an IELTS essay on this topic:

> Some people think that environmental problems are too big for
>   individuals to solve. Others, however, believe that these problems
>   cannot be solved if individuals do not take action. Discuss both views
>   and give your own opinion.

My argument is that individuals do matter in protecting the earth. One sentence I used to summarize my point and counteract the opposite argument is:

> There's no such thing as an oversized commitment that is too big for
>   one to dedicate oneself to.

I know the expression "There's no such thing as a free lunch." So, I think the structure of my sentence-- "there is no such thing as a..."-- is alright.

Still, I am not sure whether it is ok to follow the operative noun (commitment) with an adjective clause. Do people do that in their writings?

Comment: Seems you are using a format for the essay. To answer the question, IMO, the sentence looks superfluous for sure. BTW, I teach IELTS/PTE/CELPIP.

Comment: All the time. I might say, "There's no such thing as a lunch that's free." The truth of your statement is another (i.e, a non-grammatical) matter.